# Программа не выходит в главное окно

Tags: c#

Visual Studio 12, C#. 
Вот команда меню дочерней формы:

```
private void MnuToMainWind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  FMain.Visible = true;
  Close();
}
```

FMain - родительская форма, выхожу туда из дочерней. У меня - все в порядке(Windows 8.1). У пользователя (Windows 10.1 ) эти два оператора вызывают падение программы. Пытался вставить  FMain.Refresh() перед Close() - пользователю не помогло. Что предположить?

Comment: Покажите код, где из родительской формы вызывается дочерняя?

Comment: С удовольствием:


private void CreateForm(int fi, int ft)
  {
   OpenDialog.FilterIndex = fi;
   if(OpenDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
   {
    MessageBox.Show("Опять зря открыли");
    return;
   }
   Visible = false;
   FormFiles ff = new FormFiles(this);
   ff.Ft = (FILETYPE)ft;
   ff.ShowDialog();
  }

Comment: собственно, проблема в другом. Опишите сообщение об ошибке, из-за которого падает ваша программа. Без неё понять невозможно.

Comment: Что-то вроде: программа имярек заканчивает работу.

Comment: @BuilderC дочернее окно отображается как окно диалога?

Comment: @BuilderC скопируйте сообщение полностью.

Comment: Оно у пользователя.

Comment: @sp7 Как форма.

Comment: В таком случае попробуйте либо изменить при билде версию .Net Framework, либо обновите у клиента версию .Net Framework.

Comment: Поигрался и попробовал разные варианты открытия/закрытия окно. На Windows 10 ни каких проблем.